# Nami's message in Strong World movie

Tags: one-piece

In the movie Strong World, Nami sends a message to the crew via Tone Dial which is as follows:

> Please forgive me for being unable to say farewell to you all directly. I have decided to join Shiki's crew as their navigator. Shiki is a legendary pirate who you could never match up to even if you stood up to him. Even if you came after me you would only end up losing your lives. I will say this much, promise you will come rescue me.

Luffy missed to hear the last part: "*promise you will come rescue me*", but everyone else did hear it and understood it. When trying to explain Luffy, however, Sanji made a statement which caused some confusion. It goes as follows:

> ... Although to me the whole thing sounded like message of love.

This led to confusion as it seemed to be wrongly interpreted that the last part of message implied Nami loved Luffy. I also read somewhere that Nami started to blush when Luffy started playing the Dial, but I didn't see Nami blushing at all (in anime, if someone blushes, their face is shown to be turning red, right?). She did seem to be embarrassed which seemed to be normal. If I were her and someone was going to play a recording in front of everyone which I made when I was in a sad situation, I would definitely not want him to play that because it would be embarrassing.

Nami knew that Luffy won't understand indirect message (she does say she directed the last part specifically to Luffy since he is so dense). I think Nami wanted to indirectly ask the crew to come and save her, but for thick-headed Luffy, she explicitly added the last line. She just wanted Luffy and rest of crew to come and save her, there were no romantic feelings.

I tried to search online if I was right about the message's intent, but couldn't find proper sources.

For example, I found on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One_Piece_Film:_Strong_World#Plot):

> ...Luffy later learns that Nami's message was actually a coded SOS directed at him that the crew took as a love confession...

Although the above line mentions the crew mistook as a love confession, I don't think so, I think they properly understood the intent of the message. Although, I am not sure what Sanji meant by saying the above line, but it seemed he did understood the real intent.

Are there any sources which exactly tells the true intent of the message and also if the crew (except Luffy) properly understood it?

Comment: Well, I saw the movie and I didn't get any feelings of a love message. Nami had deliver the first part of the message as to assure Shiki she will stay with him and added the last part especially for the dense Luffy to understand.

Comment: @RigaCrypto, that's exactly my thoughts. Nami is clever. She fooled Shiki and asked his crewmates for help at the same time. For Luffy, she had to add that last line. However, I need some proper source to verify that.

Answer (score -1):

Oda drew a 'Strong World after 3 seconds' where you could clearly see Nami blushing and Luffy has a huge smile with his hand behind an ear (same as Sanji but we all know that those last few words were for). It's a really cute snippet. I'll send a link so you can see it.

https://dshanks-op.tumblr.com/post/158367417268/oda-drew-what-happened-after-strong-world-ended-d